# How to loop an object and push key and value into the other object

Tags: typescript, object

how can I loop an object and put all value of this object into the other object.

inputObject looks like this:

```
inputObject = {
    stations: {
        1: {name: "sdfasd"},
        2: {id: "sdfasd"}
 
    }   

}
```

the expected Object should like this:

```
{
name: "sdfasd",
id: "sdfasd"
}
```

any solution???

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the values of the object using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over them and merge them using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
const inputObject = {
  stations: {
    1: {name: "sdfasd"},
    2: {id: "sdfasd"}
  }
}

const outputObject = Object.values(inputObject.stations)
                           .reduce((result, item) => Object.assign(result, item), {})

console.log(outputObject)
```

Comment: Hi Luke, thx for your solution, but I got this error  "Spread types may only be created from object types". the ...result is red...

Comment: Is your input object in the question definitely correct? the difference between `[` and `{` means array or object, and that difference is crucial in how we handle them here.

Answer (score 0):

I put together this TypeScript code that outputs what you asked for but I'm wondering if you really meant you want an array of those objects as your output, as in one object for each *"station"*. Without more explanation of the input and expected output I can't be sure.  In any case, this code uses `Object.entries(inputObject).forEach()` loops of objects to answer your core question of how to loop through an object and put its values into another object. It should be pretty self-explanatory and can easily be expanded on.

```
let inputObject = {
  stations: {
    1: { name: "sdfasd" },
    2: { id: "sdfasd" }
  }
};

let outputObject = {};

// 2 levels of nested forEach loops to get to the deepest {key: value} objects
Object.entries(inputObject).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  Object.entries(value).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    outputObject = Object.assign(outputObject, value);
  });
});

console.log(outputObject);
// Outputs:
//
// { 
//   name: 'sdfasd',
//   id: 'sdfasd' 
// }
```